# A not-too-old, non-Asimov robot story with robots who are not bound by the Three Laws

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, laws-of-robotics

This, for a change, is a rather recent (less than 30 years old) short story or novelette. Asimov's Three Laws of Robotics are prominent in it, but it was clearly written long after The Good Doctor's demise. In particular, not all robots are built in conformity with the Three Laws.

The future it describes is also influenced by Orwell's 1984. There are also three belligerent powers, with shifting alliances, but the names are a bit different. I forgot the name of the US block, but it was **not** Oceania which was at war against the US till shortly before the story itself. Now the US block's enemy is Eurasia, but the latter is Chinese dominated, not Russian/Soviet dominated (so the story is most probably post-1991). There is no mention of East Asia. Essentially it is Eurasia that makes non-three-laws robots.

In this context the main character is a NYPD cop. He is divorced and his wife, a very able robotician, has defected to Eurasia. The story really begins when his daughter is kidnapped and he suspects that Eurasian agents did it, and that his ex-wife is behind that. Which is mostly true

> but for the fact it was not **really** a kidnapping, in fact his ex-wife **convinced** her daughter to come with her.

He finds Eurasian agents, some of which are non-three-laws robots, as per Eurasian usual standards, and is unable to overcome them. But he also has trouble with US secret agents some of which are **also** non-three-laws robots which should be illegal by US standard, except that Secret Services seem above the law.
Beyond that it becomes so complicated that I have trouble telling what comes next.

I read it in French, but I am not sure whether it is a French original or a translation from English. I don't remember what kind of support that was. I remember there was some non-fiction together with it, about Asimov, his Three Laws of Robotics and their impact on SF, with the story put there as a example. Everything was in French.

Comment: We had this one come up recently.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Well, before posting I **always** check everything that is suggested in the box that automatically opens when one starts typing a new question. I did not see there any question that dealt with a 1984-type future with non-three-laws robots. I did not make an independent check, just look at the site's automatic one.

Comment: @Alfred FWIW the suggestions given in that box are usually awful. The site's search feature in general is pretty poor.

Comment: So how should I do to avoid duplicates ? I relied on that box. I don't know how to look for keywords. For instance,  Oceania and Eurasia might have found duplicates (three laws being a bit too general)

Comment: @Alfred: Sorry, didn't mean to seem to criticize. I wanted to let you know it existed and then was going to search, but work happened and I just got back to my desk.

Comment: @Alfred I think you'd have struggled to find the duplicate as the other question has a different emphasis. I didn't realise it was a duplicate until after I posted, when I searched for the story title. I wouldn't worry about it. It does no harm to have duplicates as it makes it easier for people visiting the site to search.

Comment: Well, it is indeed a duplicate. But it is amusing to remark how different people have different memories. What I remembered was the discrepancy between the names of the countries in this story with respect to Orwell's 1984. And the kidnapping that was not one. Evan B remembered the end of the story much better than I did but described the ex-wife as a “rebel leader” when I remembered that she was a robotician of high standing in her new country (though considered a traitor, with good reasons, in her original one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I, Robot](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?377131) by Cory Doctorow.

The policeman is:

> Arturo Icaza de Arana-Goldberg, Police Detective Third Grade, United North American Trading Sphere, Third District, Fourth Prefecture, Second Division (Parkdale) had had many adventures in his distinguished career, running crooks to ground with an unbeatable combination of instinct and unstinting devotion to duty.

And his wife:

> His ex-wife. He hadn’t thought of her in years. Well, months. Weeks, certainly. She’d been a brilliant computer scientist, the valedictorian of her Positronic Complexity Engineering class at the UNATS Robotics school at the University of Toronto. Dumping her husband and her daughter was bad enough, but the worst of it was that she dumped her country and its way of life. Now she was ensconced in her own research lab in Beijing, making the kinds of runaway Positronics that made the loathsome robots of UNATS look categorically beneficent.

As you say the Eurasians are building robots that don't conform to the three laws. Arturo encounters one such robot:

> But it gave Arturo the willies. It was a machine designed to kill other machines, and that was all right with him, but it was run by a non-three-laws positronic brain. Someone in some Eurasian lab had built this brain—this machine intelligence—without the three laws’ stricture to protect and serve humans. If it had been outfitted with a gun instead of a pulse-weapon, it could have shot him.

Comment: Wow ! That was fast. The description of the ex-wife was enough to convince me that's the one.